# Angular - Displaying array as list in frontend

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm working on my web-app and I am facing a problem.

I have an array with several values, which I'd like to display in the frontend as list or something similar.

**app.component.ts**

*in this function I split the tags from the string into an array*

```
splitTags() {
  if (this.data.tags != null) {
    var tag = this.data.tags.split(";")
    console.log(tag)
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.splitTags()
}
```

**app.component.html**

*here I d'like to display the tags in a list*

```
<li *ngFor="let tag in tags">
  {{ tag }}
</li>
```

but nothing appears, also if I see the values in the console.

Comment: You need to use `of` not `in`: `<li *ngFor="let tag of tags">`

Comment: @AndreiTătar yes and there is another error he don't store the result of split method in a componenet property 

Comment: where is your "tags" property in the app.component.ts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a property to hold the `split` result

```js
tags:any[]; // 1️⃣

splitTags() {
  if (this.data.tags != null) {
    this.tags = this.data.tags.split(";"); // 2️⃣
    console.log(this.tags)
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.splitTags()
}
```

*template*

```html
<li *ngFor="let tag of tags">
  {{ tag }}
</li>
```

Comment: @malbaravi - I've an other question: I added now a limit of 5 in my list. But sometimes there are more than 5 values in that array. How can I add a button "show all" and then display everything in that list?

Comment: @macintosh11 check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbck7s may help 